# What's with this scroll code

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, markdown

See this this question-revision (next revision is corrected): https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4611363/3

Long pieces of code get put into a scrollable component which is understandable, however in the middle of this code there is another scrollable component which makes the scrolling very weird and makes it easy to miss some of the lines of code.

Comment: It's wrapped in HTML, not markdown. Things like that are possible with HTML on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Whoever's voting to close this as off-topic... do me a favor and go look at the link.

Comment: @Anna Lear: It's a question about code, THEREFORE IT BELONGS ON STACK OVERFLOW!!! It's also link-only, therefore it would be closed there too. Hence, off-topic on-meta-site.

Comment: What did I do wrong? I don't understand. Is bug reporting not done here? Do you want me to copy the code that causes the bug to this question?

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong. Bug reporting is done here. And you don't really have to copy any code over - you might not be able to fully reproduce the problem anyway. Some close voters are just dimwits.

Answer (score 6):

Not only is that code block set up with HTML instead of Markdown, but the opening/closing tags were flipped: `<pre><code>` and the start and `</pre></code>` at the end. For some reason, that resulted in a second scrollbar... I swapped the closing tags and it's all good now.

I feel pretty strongly "meh" on digging in to figure out exactly *why* this happened since this is very much in the "fixed with a quick edit" category, but there you go. A parsing oddity.

My advice remains to use Markdown unless it is *absolutely necessary* to sprinkle some HTML in.